# During scroll add a class and if scroll ended remove class

Tags: jquery, scroll

I searched in different post and could not find the answer for a jQuery which responds only on scroll, no matter which position. I would like to have a code that on scroll adds a class and when scroll is finished remove this class.

For now I have something like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop()){
        $('.site-header').addClass('ipad-on-scroll');
    }else{
        $('.site-header').removeClass('ipad-on-scroll');
    }
});
```

This is not working, how would it be correct?

Comment: can u be more specific when you want to add class and when to remove it ..

Comment: @Saurabh I would like to add the class only while scrolling. This class has a display none and I would like the header to dissapear while scrolling, once finished the scroll I would like it to appear again. any ideas?

Comment: this may help you http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_event_scrollstop

Answer (score 2):

> Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    $('.site-header').toggleClass('ipad-on-scroll');

});
```

Comment: Your code makes sense, I tried and it does toggle. The issue is that it toggles after the scroll so sometimes you end the scroll and the element dissapears (ipad-on-scroll has a display none). I would like the element to only dissapear while there is a scroll, is this the correct path?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    // stuff
});
```

Here's the [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Answer (score 0):

create css for your class 'ipad-on-scroll' first.

display it on scroll like below.

Using jQuery.

```
$('.site-header').scroll(function() {
   $('ipad-on-scroll').css( "display", "inline" ).fadeOut( "fast" );            
});
```

try this.

Comment: But I would like the class to be added only DURING the scroll, after the scroll is finished I would like to remove this class.

Answer (score 0):

I this what you are looking for

as `if` in jQuery checks for true or false value and
`$(window).scrollTop()` returns a integer value just check that and you are done.

so it the `scrollTop() == 0` means it is on top else it is on scroll

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/9BHtv/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this does not solve my question.  If the site is on scroll add a class if not remove this class.

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero did you check the demo i did the same thing there

Comment: I checked the demo but its not what I mean. Your demo applies the class if scrolled but when the scroll finishes the header is still not displayed. What I want is if the scroll has finished then remove the class.